# Cannot import 3rd party JavaScript module

Tags: javascript, html, import, mime-types, algorand

I'm attempting to import a 3rd party SDK into a simple project with a very simple setup. I have an index.html file that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <body>
    <h1>SDK Test</h1>
    <script type="module" src="/js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have a main.js file that looks like this:

```
import MyAlgoConnect from '/@randlabs/myalgo-connect';
console.log("It Worked!");
```

I also have the @randlabs directory in my project running on an Apache server, so that in Apache's htdocs directory, it looks like this:

[image]

But I always get an error in my browser console that says:

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

I originally tried using `<script src="/js/main.js"></script>` in the index.html file, but it returned with the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at main.js:3:1)
```

There's a whole bunch of different files and additional folders within the myalgo-connect folder, so when I try going to my local apache server at `127.0.0.1:8080/@randlabs/myalgo-connect` in my browser it just returns an html document showing the contents of the folder, which is why I assume I'm getting an error in the first place.

According to the SDK's documentation, I think I'm following its Quick Start steps exactly: https://connect.myalgo.com/docs/getting-started/quickstart

I've been searching the internet for days trying to figure out why I can't get this to work. I've also asked a question on the associated discord server but haven't had a response. My experience with web development is very limited, so this is probably just an issue of inexperience on my part, but I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. If anyone can shed some light on this, I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to setup basic node processor which then compiles application into js file.

https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html

https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started

I recommend also to setup the TypeScript as it helps a lot with data types and recommendations.

This is example how you can use the MyAlgoConnect by Randlabs (React): https://github.com/Diatomix/Diatomix-frontend/blob/dff9a531ceac4341a3780c004f2bc2206b255ed4/src/components/Authenticate.tsx#L163

Example how to use Algorand with Vue.js : https://github.com/scholtz/wallet

Comment: Thank you! Once I tried installing it into a Vue.js project, it all worked as it was supposed to.